# jquery (mobile) - bind a tap event to a div

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

If I have this html:

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

and this CSS:

```
#myDiv{
    background:url('../images/someImage.png') no-repeat;
    background-size:100%;
    width:44px;
    height:44px;

}
```

I need to open a new page when the user taps on myDiv. I have an external js file where I have this:

```
function bindMyDiv(){
    $("#myDiv").bind('tap',function(event, ui){
        alert("binding");
    })
}
```

But I don't understand where to call this from the HTML, or if this is even the right way to go about this. Advice?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$("#myDiv").live("tap", function(event){
  alert('binding');
});
```

You can place this in side your `onReady` javascript file

EDIT:

http://jsfiddle.net/R9e6u/

Comment: You shouldn't need to place that inside a `document.ready` event handler because it's event delegation so it binds directly to the `document` element which is always available. Also `.delegate()` is preferred over `.live()` and as of jQuery 1.7, `.live()` is depreciated.

Comment: You are correct however currently jQuery is supported up to 1.6.4 which uses `live` instead of `on`

Comment: This is from the documentation for `.delegate()`: `As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method. For earlier versions, however, it remains the most effective means to use event delegation.` So if you're using jQuery 1.4.2 or newer, then the jQuery team recommends the use of `.delegate()`.

Answer (score 1):

Everyone here provided pretty good insight on different solutions for you to handle your script, but I don't think that anyone stopped to think SHOULD they help improve your script. "or if this is even the right way to go about this ", the answer is no. And perhaps I'm over-simplifying, but with JQM if you're trying to have a div (or any DOM element for that matter) open a new page simply wrap an anchor tag around around it (or in it, whichever is appropriate) and set your href to `href="#myNewPage"`and the id on the JQM page that you want to load to `id="myNewPage"`

jQuery Mobile's frame work is set up to automatically inject JS & AJAX into normal HTML elements to provide a smooth UX. While binding a touch event is sometime needed, this situation doesn't warrant that level of code...thats the beauty of jQuery Mobile =).

Examples of when to bind a touch event: show/hide a dom object, trigger a click for a plug-in etc.

Comment: he don't want to link to  new jqm page, he want to bind it to a function.

Answer (score 0):

You want to call that function on the `pageinit` event for the page on which it resides. You could use some other page-events from jQuery Mobile like: `pagecreate`, `pageshow`, etc. but I think `pageinit` is your best-bet.

The implementation would look something like this:

```
$(document).delegate('#page-id', 'pageinit', function () {
    $("#myDiv").bind('tap',function(event, ui){
        alert("binding");
    })
});
```

OR

```
$(document).delegate('#page-id', 'pageinit', bindMyDiv);
```

You would replace `#page-id` with the ID of the `data-role="page"` element in which your div resides.

This method is preferred over event delegation for the `#myDiv` element because binding directly to an element creates less overhead when the event is triggered. If you use event delegation then the event has to bubble-up to the delegation root.